# Is there a way to auto-fill multiple incrementing values in the blank rows below each value in the same column without dragging? - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[rows as described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAk90.png)

See image. Basically, I have a column with initial values, and then I want the incrementing values to auto-fill in under each of them in the blank rows. So for example, I have a cell with value 145-1, followed by 3 blank rows, and then 146-1, followed by one blank row, etc. Right now I'm just dragging 145-1 down the 3 blank rows to populate 145-2, 145-3, and 145-4, then dragging 146-1 down one row, so on and so forth.

I'm wondering if there's a way to get these to auto-fill in the blank rows below each value rather than having to manually drag each of them down to populate the subsequent values. If there's a way to do it in Excel but not Google Sheets, that works too.

Let me know if any of that was confusing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column in A1:An just containing the initial '-1' values for each group, you can generate another column containing both these and the the missing -2,-3,...-n values using the following formula:

```
=arrayformula(let(
splitcol,iferror(split(A1:An,"-")),
lhside,scan(,choosecols(splitcol,1),lambda(acc,arr,if(arr="",acc,arr))),
rhside,scan(,choosecols(splitcol,2),lambda(acc,arr,if(arr="",acc+1,arr))),
lhside&"-"&rhside))
```

Obviously change the range A1:An to suit your requirements.